# Laravel access to object attribute

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, query-builder

I have problem with how to access name of the attribute of object. the value return from 'sql query" is object for this method of Laravel.

```
$report= DB::select('SELECT * from user');
```

Usually, I work with associative arrays so I can access to key of the array by using

```
 @foreach($reports as $key => $report)
 <td>{{$key}}</td>
 @endforeach`
```

but with object I cannot do that. So, I tried to convert object to array by using `toArray()` method but also it is not work. How can I access to name of attribute to print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object access this way:

```
$reports = DB::select('SELECT * from user');

@foreach($reports as $r)
 <td>{{$r->name}}</td>
@endforeach`
```

or you can change fetching mode:

```
$mode = DB::getFetchMode();
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$reports = DB::select('SELECT * from users');
DB::setFetchMode($mode);
```

and now use:

```
@foreach($reports as $key => $report)
 <td>{{$key}} {{$report['name]}}</td>
@endforeach`
```

Answer (score 0):

try lists in example :

> $row = DB::table('table_name')
>                                   ->select('name','id')
>                                   ->where('status','active')
>                                   ->lists('name','id');